# Proof by Induction that for a full non-empty binary tree (N nodes, L leafs), N = 2L - 1

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes, induction

So I assume the base case is N = 1?

I'm starting with 2L-1=2L-3+2=[2(L-1)-1]+2, but I don't know where to go from there.

How should I go about the induction proof?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: 1) Count the number of {l,r} pointers. 2) count the number of nodes. 3) who points at the root node?